# Get GMT offset from timezone string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to return `-05:00` from the string `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)` with regex. I know this is a tedious question, but I have been researching for a couple of minutes and have gotten nowhere. Can anyone help? Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What have you tried?

You could use `[+-][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\b` which matches a plus or minus sign followed by 'dd:dd' where 'd' is a digit. The trailing `\b` makes sure that something like `-12:234565` won't match.

Comment: Perfect, I was trying to capture (GMT ... ) which is, in retrospect very stupid.